# symfony - can I use traits to instantiate serializer

Tags: symfony

I am currently using [Symfony serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) in my controller method, but since I need to use it in Controller and even multiple Controllers (and its methods) is there any way to create this in traits and use it on the fly where I need it?
if not traits, is it possible to instantiate it once at the start of the class and then use it as

> $this->serializer->serialize(...);

or I just have to instantiate it in every method I write?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to say here.

First of all, if your controllers extends the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController :

- You have access to a shortcut method "$this->json($data, int $status = 200, array $headers = [], array $context = [])" which use the serializer to serialize in json.
- Since the AbstractController implements the ServiceSubscriberInterface and it subscribe to the serializer if present, you can even access it through "$this->get('serializer')". I don't like this method personnally.

If your controllers doesn't extend the AbstractController or if, like me, you prefer to use depency injection via the constructor :

- You can inject the serializer thanks to the autowiring in the constructor

  ```
  /** @var SerializerInterface */
  private $serializer;

  public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer)
  {
      $this->serializer = $serializer;
  }
  ```

But you have to do this for all your controllers

- You can implements the Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareInterface to inject the serializer quickly :

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Controller;

  use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareTrait;

  class MyController implements SerializerAwareInterface
  {
      use SerializerAwareTrait;

      public function myAction()
      {
          $this->serializer->serialize(...);

          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

I hope this will answer to your question.